# libiconv.2.dylib Mountain Lion issue

Tags: macos, git, libiconv

Anytime I'm try to install something **git** dependent (**homebrew** for example) I get this error:

```
> Incompatible library version: git requires version 8.0.0 or later, but
> libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

I've reinstalled git and **xcode** but the error keeps being thrown. I don't have **macports** installed.

Anyone have ideas on how to solve?

Comment: Find out which version `git` is loading `otool -L $(which git) | grep iconv`.

Comment: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)

Comment: And btw: It does seem that two versions are installed: `/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)` and `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)`

Comment: Have you installed the cmd line tools in Xcode as well?

Comment: @themexican: libiconv and libSystem are different libraries.